# google Maps Api vs Bing Maps for C#

Tags: c#, google-maps, bing-maps

I want to use one of this services for maps in my website. Which do you think I should go for provided that the application is writen in C#. Which is the best SDK for working with this services in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest taking a look at this:

http://www.jonasson.org/maps/

I had to make the same decision a couple of years ago, and when using this it was clear that Google Maps had much better satellite imagery, and road data than Bing Maps (specifically in the locations our customers would be using it)

The Bing Maps API is coded in a very familiar .Net fashion. Although its all JavaScript, the Google API feels more like a Java implementation (as you might expect). This take some time to get your head around, but shouldn't really be an issue.

I found the Maps Group on Google excellent as a resource for research and queries.

**UPDATE:**

Google released v 3 of their API recently and its supports street view as part of the maps API. Pretty compelling reason to use it.

Answer (score 2):

use [great maps api](http://greatmaps.codeplex.com/) instead it is an open source project and very useful. You can change the maps from bing,yahoo to google maps.Of course you should take the api key for google and bing. The documentation is not enough but i think it is very easy to use. Hope this helps.

Comment: sorry i did not see the "my website" this api for winforms.

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat subjective; however, go for what you believe would provide the best service to your "customers" (whoever they may be).  I would not let your determination be based on what "SDK is best" per se, as you can find a hundred examples out there to do both bing maps and google maps.  As far as popularity, I would imagine google maps takes the cake:

Try this google maps example: [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/RazorMaps.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

For my needs (and yours may well be very different) the parts of the API I use are easiest to access via Javascript in both cases.  The big win for me in the app I'm working on right now is the Silverlight control for Bing maps, and the ease of integration into a WP7 app.